# ListData.svc REST and URL Encoding of Field 'Parts Released?'

Tags: url, rest, listdata.svc

I have a field with the display name `Parts Released?` but I cannot seem to figure out how to encode the field name. I have tried `Parts Released%3f` but regardless of what I try I get a 400 Bad Request as my response.

How would I encode `Parts Released?` with a question mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the rules for working with List field names and List names in REST.

> Preserve casing, remove spaces and keep the first letter of each
>   individual word as Capital. For example a field with display name
>   "home aDdress" will be "HomeADdress".
>
> If a special character like dot is in field name or List name it is to
>   be treated like space i.e. if field name is "Add.ress" the REST
>   equivalent will be "AddRess"

[SOURCE](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/06/field-names-in-rest-query-are-case.html)

Answer (score 3):

Spaces are trimmed and the special characters are omitted

`Parts Released?` becomes `PartsReleased` and if anyone suspects this is the fields internal name, the ListData.svc does not use internal names. The internal name is completely different.

Comment: +1 for proactively handling the internal name question!